# Followed tutorial exactly, UITableView will not work

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to learn how to use the UITableView element, however despite watching a simple tutorial and copying the code character for character, the table view still crashes the application despite not raising any errors in the editor.

Code:

```
import UIKit

class viewFriendsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var dataSource: [String] = []

var items = ["one", "two"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataSource = ["new orleans", "San Fransisco", "Seattle", "New York", "London"]
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("homeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

}
```

Error:

> 2015-11-05 13:51:49.120 collaboration[17405:218899] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key myTableView.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ac16f45 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010c93adeb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010ac16b89 -[NSException raise] + 9   3   Foundation
>
>   0x000000010afdfa6b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] +
>   288   4   UIKit                               0x000000010b5be04c
>   -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88     5   UIKit                               0x000000010b7eba71 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109   6
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ab57a80 -[NSArray
>   makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224    7   UIKit
>
>   0x000000010b7ea454 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864  8
>
>   UIKit                               0x000000010b5c4c16
>   -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381   9   UIKit                               0x000000010b5c5542 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178   10  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010b5c58a0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138   11 
>   UIKit                               0x000000010b5c6013
>   -[UIViewController view] + 27     12  UIKit                               0x000000010bd687e7 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController
>   _setPresentedViewController:] + 87    13  UIKit                               0x000000010b595dde -[UIPresentationController
>   initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 133  14 
>   UIKit                               0x000000010b5d89ba
>   -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4004     15  UIKit                               0x000000010b5dbc5c
>   -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 489   16  UIKit                               0x000000010b5db76b
>   -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179  17  UIKit                               0x000000010b5e0e0f
>   -[UIViewController _showViewController:withAction:sender:] + 280  18  UIKit                               0x000000010ba2b130
>   __66-[UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 147     19  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010bb527c4 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate
>   _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 460  20  UIKit                               0x000000010bb525c7 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82  21 
>   UIKit                               0x000000010bb5288b
>   -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156   22  UIKit                               0x000000010b434e91 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>     23  UIKit                               0x000000010b5a04d8
>   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     24  UIKit                               0x000000010b5a07a4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
>     25  UIKit                               0x000000010b59f8d4
>   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601    26  UIKit                               0x000000010b4a2ed1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835  27  UIKit 
>   0x000000010b4a3c06 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865   28  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010b4532fa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263  29  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010b42dabf _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844  30 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ab43011
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ab38f3c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556   32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ab383f3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867     33  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010ab37e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488     34  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010f20aad2 GSEventRunModal + 161  35  UIKit
>   0x000000010b43330d UIApplicationMain + 171    36  collaboration
>   0x000000010aa22f6d main + 109     37  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010d44292d start + 1  38  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Thanks

Comment: Did you do something in storyboard with your `ViewController`, add `UITableView` and custom cells?

Comment: What? Sorry, I do not understand what you mean...

Comment: Somthing in your code is trying to access `myTableView`. Which does not exist. Did you maybe rename the table view property?

Comment: @Nick, Check datasource and delgate connection of your tableview and add below code in your viewdidload() : Your_tableName.dataSorce=self;Your_tableName.delegate=self;

Answer (score 1):

Go to storyboard, right click on your tableView and check whether it's outlet is connected to name "myTableView" or not. If yes, then disconnect it using the cross icon. I guess your tableView is having two outlets, one named "myTableView" and other "tableView". Make sure you keep the name the one in your code.

Answer (score 0):

First Thing first:

```
Connect the IBOutlet to the actual UITableView Object (CTRL + Drag)
```

Then connect TableView Delegate to self  in viewDidLoad()

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

And Also make sure that you gave the cell name is the same as **homeCell**